# Replace last values by previous value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

I have array of uncomplete triples:

```
a = np.arange(10) // 3 + 1
print (a)
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4]
```

Or:

```
a1 = np.arange(11) // 3 + 1
print (a1)
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4]
```

Last value is `4`, but I need change it by previous, here `3`, because not triples.

I try:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
print (unique)
[1 2 3 4]

print (counts)
[3 3 3 1]
```

Expected output for `a`:

```
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
```

and for `a1`:

```
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3]
```

If all triples, no value is changed:

```
a2 = np.arange(12) // 3 + 1
print (a2)

[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4]
```

I need some general solution, because triples should be changed to `4` or more.

Comment: What should the solution for `[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4]` be?

Comment: last `4 4` should be changed to `3 3` - `[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3]`

Comment: what about `[1 1 2 2 2]`?

Comment: arrays are created by floor, so it is not possible.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
def replace_irregular_groupings(a, N=3):
    n = len(a)
    m = N*(n//N)
    if m!=n:
        a[m:] = a[m-1]
    return a
```

Sample runs -

```
In [125]: replace_irregular_groupings(np.arange(9) // 3 + 1)
Out[125]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])

In [126]: replace_irregular_groupings(np.arange(10) // 3 + 1)
Out[126]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])

In [127]: replace_irregular_groupings(np.arange(11) // 3 + 1)
Out[127]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

In [128]: replace_irregular_groupings(np.arange(12) // 3 + 1)
Out[128]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

Comment: What about `[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 7]`?

Comment: @Elmex80s - problem should be only in last group, so never this data.

Comment: @Elmex80s That doesn't adhere to the criteria of triplets there, does it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def complete(array, n):
    remain = array.size % n
    complete_array = array.copy()
    if remain != 0:
        complete_array[-remain:] = complete_array[-n]
    return complete_array
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
def filler(a,n=3):
    if len(np.unique(a[-n:])) == 1:
        return a
    else:
        a[-n:].fill(a[-n-1])
        return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (I'm not sure about the numpy conversion since I've never used numpy)

```
a = np.arrange(12) // 3 + 1
a = a.tolist()

num = len(a) // 3
num2 = len(a) % 3
b = []
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    b.append(i)
    b.append(i)
    b.append(i)

for j in range(1, num2 + 1):
    b.append(num)

print(b)
```

Comment: **Moderator note:** Let's keep comments constructive and civil please.